# tp-link TL-WR841ND WIRELESS ROUTER

Tags: wireless-networking

How many wireless connections can be made through tp-link TL-WR841ND? I have potentially 17 devices (phones, ipads, computers, alexa, TV, alarm system, etc), with a number of them operating simultaneously, as they need to be always on.

Answer (score 0):

#### How many wireless connections can be made through tp-link TL-WR841ND?

Usually a maximum of 254 devices:

- The number of DHCP address is limited by the  subnet mask, which is usually 255.255.255.0.
- This limits the number of DHCP clients to 255, but one IP address is always taken by the router so 254 is the max.

However, this maximum is not usually practical and here's why:

> **Practical Limits of Wi-Fi Network Scaling**
>
> Connecting 250 devices to a single Wi-Fi access point, while
>   theoretically possible, is not feasible in practice for a few reasons:
>
> - On home networks, all devices normally share a single internet connection. The performance of clients' access will start to degrade
>     as more devices join the network and start using it simultaneously.
>     Even just a handful of active devices streaming video or downloading
>     files can quickly max out a shared internet link.
> - Access points overheat and stop working when operating at extreme loads for extended periods, even if handling only local traffic and
>     not accessing the internet.
> - Having a large number of WiFi clients concentrated in close physical proximity, like a home or office building, generates
>     significant wireless signal interference. Radio interference among
>     Wi-Fi clients degrades network performance (due to frequent
>     re-broadcasting of messages that fail to reach their destination) and
>     eventually causes connection drops.
> - Some home routers include a feature that allows administrators to control the number of clients that can simultaneously connect. Many
>     Linksys routers, for example, set a default maximum of 50 maximum
>     clients. Administrators often keep a limit like this in place to keep
>     the router and network running reliably.

Source [How Many Devices Can One Wireless Router Handle?](https://www.lifewire.com/how-many-devices-can-share-a-wifi-network-818298)